# RavenDB Dynamic Collection Access

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, ravendb, nosql

I have request object for some wacky dynamic grid function my boss wrote. One of the properties in this request object is the name of a entity or the collection name for the document store coming into a web api controller.

```
            IDocumentQuery<T> context = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<T>();

            context = AddSearchToContext(context, _searchRequest.Search, _searchRequest.DataFilters.Any());

            context = AddFiltersToContext(context, _searchRequest.DataFilters);

            context.Take(1).ToList();

            RavenQueryStatistics stats = null;
            context.Statistics(out stats);


            return stats.TotalResults;
```

Now I have some code that looks like this for testing purposes and so far so good but my main problem is the Type of T. The Type is required for the raven api to realize what collection is being inspected. My problem is I only have a string of the entity name coming in, not the type, and my only idea so far is writing a huge switch statement filled with the same code over and over again for each type.

Is there a "dynamic" or generic way I can avoid repeating all my code over and over again in a switch statement? Can I use reflection? Any tips would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "object", and force the query anyway using:

```
IDocumentQuery<object> context = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<object>("dynamic/" + collectionName);
```